# Slack bot that goes out and reads data from external page then posts?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I have an external website that has some dynamic data on it that refreshes regularly. I'd like to set up a Slack bot reaches out to that site (maybe by a curl or with screen scraping) and return the first line of data into a message in a channel.

I browsed some integrations and I haven't found anything that fits the bill quite yet. I don't have control over the external site to put a send to Slack button on it.

Thanks!

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward... could you share your code so far? Or at least tell us what programming language you want to use? (As it is, this question may be too open-ended for Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the curl/scraping part works as intended, you should have no specific issue. When the user types either a slash command or a bot keyword, you can perform the scraping from your server then:

- if it was a slash command, use a delayed response (you have up to 30min to respond, see documentation https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_a_command)
- If the request came from a bot, simply post the text in the channel as a standard message

It would help if you shared more details about the framework you use or even share your code

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing your bot in `Go`, you are more than welcome to use my Slack Bot framework https://github.com/shomali11/slacker

You can easily create a bot that responds to mentions and direct messages then respond back.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/shomali11/slacker"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    bot := slacker.NewClient("<YOUR SLACK BOT TOKEN>")

    bot.Command("ping", "Ping!", func(request *slacker.Request, response *slacker.Response) {
        response.Reply("pong")
    })

    bot.Command("read <url>", "Read content of a URL", func(request *slacker.Request, response *slacker.Response) {
        urlContent := readData(request.Param("url"))
        response.Reply(urlContent)
    })

    err := bot.Listen()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

As for the `readData` method, reading data from external pages should be relatively straightforward in `Go`. Here is an example using [gorequest](https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest):

```
request := gorequest.New()
response, body, errs := request.Get("http://example.com/").End()
```